# mt4 indicators fibonacci / I want to delete fibonacci

Tags: fibonacci, indicator, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I want to delete my "`Fibo`", the one which I made by the ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533863/mt4-indicators-fibonacci-i-want-to-delete-fibonacci)*** ( ref.: missing ) indicator, but I wouldn't like to delete all "`Fibo`"s present in the **`MT4.graph`**.

How to do that?

Comment: you might want to post a picture about your problem. May post a link & I can include your illustration so as to become visible on StackOverflow, ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to delete a GUI object from an `MT4.graph`

In any case, each `MT4.graph` is composed from both individual, fully **manageable-objects** ( which can be moderated and also deleted ) **and** fixed, **system-driven objects** ( which can have adapted only a few visualisation parameters -- a color, object appearance, scale -- within a system-driven range of values ).

This said, `Fibo`-objects are fully manageable objects, be that performed by an **`MQL4`**-code or by a user manual intervention.

For the latter case, such GUI-object has to be first moved into a **`GUI-SELECTED`**-state, for which a mouse double-click shall be used.

Once **`SELECTED`**, the GUI-object starts to become depicted with white control-points on the `MT4.graph` ( three-control-points for `Fibo` on `{0|50|100}`-lines ):

[image]

Next one may right-click with the mouse and `MT4.graph` opens another dialogue box ( depicted above ) where an option to **`Delete`** ( a `SELECTED` object(s) ) appears.

Another way is to mark and let delete such object via <kbd>**`Ctrl`**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**`B`**</kbd> which opens an **`Object-List`** window dialogue panel. The circled marker allows to switch an object's `SELECTED` state `{on|OFF}`. The button <kbd>**`Delete`**</kbd> is self-explanatory.

[image]

### It is that simple.

---

**Enjoy the Worlds of `MQL4`**